# Nightwatch(PageObject) access elements from different page object

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, nightwatch.js, pageobjects

Is there a way to access elements defined in one page object file from another page object file?

Example:
If we need to access '@usernameInput' from LoginPage.ts file, do we need to duplicate it from HomePage.ts ? Is there any other way?

```js
HomePage.ts
  const page: PageObject = {
    url: ...,
    commands: [
    enterUsername: (query: string) => {
      return this
        .waitForElementVisible('@usernameInput')
  }],
    elements: {
      usernameInput: {
        locateStrategy: 'xpath',
        selector: '//input[@name="Username"]',
      }
  };

LoginPage.js
  const page: PageObject = {
    url: ...,
    commands: [
    enterUsername: (query: string) => {
      return this
        .waitForElementVisible('@usernameInput')
  }],
    elements: {}
  };
```

Answer (score 4):

You can access one page object from another by using `this.api.page.pageObjectName`.

In your example you would just do

```
const loginPage = this.api.page.loginPage();
```

And then to get the `usernameInput` element you can just do this

```
const usernameInput = loginPage.elements.usernameInput.selector;
```

So your `enterUsername` function should look something like the following

```
enterUsername: (query: string) => {
  const loginPage = this.api.page.loginPage();
  const usernameInput = loginPage.elements.usernameInput.selector;

  return this
    .waitForElementVisible(usernameInput)
    .setValue(usernameInput, query);
}
```

Comment: No problem? Did it work? If so, could you accept the answer?

Answer (score 0):

**Use LocalStoreage to keep your data and access in all the page using Javascript or Jquery**

**Set your Object**

localStorage.setItem("PortPlans", PortPlans);

**call your localstorage in another page**

var  PortPlans = localStorage.getItem("PortPlans");

console.log(PortPlans);